# python: comparar lista que contém várias listas com uma lista diferente única

Tags: python

Estou resolvendo uma questão onde tenho de fazer um programa que corrija provas. O programa recebe um gabarito e as respostas de "n" alunos e compara com o gabarito fornecido. As respostas de todos os alunos são postas em uma lista única. Meu problema é, como comparar a lista das respostas com o gabarito e imprimir uma nota individual para cada aluno.

Ex:

```
gabarito = ['a','b','c','d','e']

resposta_alunos = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','d'],['a', 'a', 'c', 'd','d'],...]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tentei fazer algo o mais simples possível. Veja:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
respostas = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['d', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd'],
    ['d', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
    ['d', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'e']
];

gabarito = ['d', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'e']

for r_num, resposta in enumerate(respostas):

    total = 0;

    for g_num, valor in enumerate(gabarito):

        # Se a posição do valor do gabarito é o mesmo da resposta e os valores iguais

        if resposta[g_num] == valor:
            #Suponhamos que cada acerto vale 2 pontos
            total = total + 2; 

    print "O aluno %s tirou %d pontos" % (r_num, total)
```

Ao rodar o código acima, o resultado deverá ser:

```
O aluno 0 tirou 4 pontos
O aluno 1 tirou 6 pontos
O aluno 2 tirou 6 pontos
O aluno 3 tirou 10 pontos
```

Supondo que você tenha alguma noção de `python`, perceba que o trecho `resposta[g_num]` eu capturo através do índice do gabarito o valor de uma das respostas. Isso porque, em um gabarito, há um número da questão (que seria o índice em nosso caso), e, portanto, devem bater, ao mesmo tempo, o número da questão e valor da resposta.

Foi o que consegui. Não sei se nesse caso o uso de um `list` seria ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Um outra possibilidade é usar o `numpy`.

Utilizando os dados da resposta do @wallace-maxters, a gente pode obter a quantidade de acertos da seguinte forma.

```
import numpy as np

respostas = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['d', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd'],
    ['d', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
    ['d', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'e']
];

gabarito = ['d', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'e']

# Transforma em um array
respostas_arr = np.array(respostas)
gabarito_arr = np.array(gabarito)

# Verifica os acertos
verificacao = respostas_arr == gabarito_arr
#[[False False  True False  True]
# [ True  True  True False False]
# [ True  True False  True False]
# [ True  True  True  True  True]]

# Soma os acertos
acertos = verificacao.sum(1)
#[2 3 3 5]

# Imprime os resultados
for n, i in enumerate(acertos):
    print('O aluno {} acertou {} questões'.format(n+1, i))
#O aluno 1 acertou 2 questões
#O aluno 2 acertou 3 questões
#O aluno 3 acertou 3 questões
#O aluno 4 acertou 5 questões
```

Compactando tudo em uma linha:

```
acertos = (np.array(respostas) == np.array(gabarito)).sum(1)
#[2, 3, 3, 5]
```